# Magento 1.9 Create new Magento Rest API to get category list

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, category-tree, rest-api, php-5.6

I am very confused about what kind of mistake I am doing to follow these steps provided here at the following link :

> [Create new Magento Rest API to get category list in
> Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037773/create-new-magento-rest-api-to-get-category-list-in-magento?rq=1)

After doing all these steps and even editing, after reading all the solutions still getting the same error as getting before the implementation of this link steps.

To Create a new Magento Rest API to get category list in Magento 1.9,
**Where I can get the category tree?**

Comment: can you please which error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "15325833");
$ch = curl_init("http://website.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Length: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$request = "http://website.com/rest/V1/categories";  
$ch = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(json_decode($result));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Magento 2 allows access without authentication for few endpoints, which are declared as anonymous resources

```
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Services > Magento Web API > Web API Security > Allow Anonymous Guest Access
```

Now, It is possible to get the categories without authentication by using this endpoint. and run url in postman.

```
http://example.com/rest/V1/categories
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 By default, you get all the categories including all root categories too.

**Try This Steps:**

**Request:** `{{your_base_url}}/rest/all/V1/categories`

**Method:** `Get`

**Your Headers should be** - Authorization Bearer "youradminaccesstoken"